# From SQL Server to Postgres

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures

I'm new to Postgresql; I have only used SQL Server before so I'm trying to migrate an ASP.NET MVC application to ASP.NET Core 3.0 and replace SQL Server with PostgreSQL in the process, and move to Ubuntu.

Can anyone tell what's wrong with my query here?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE officekit.testsp (mode CHARACTER)
LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $plpgsql$
BEGIN
    IF mode = 'test' THEN
        SELECT a,b,c,d FROM testSchema.test;
    END IF;
    COMMIT;
END;
$plpgsql$;
```

Comment: have you tried using same schema? `testSchema.testsp` as your proc name?

Comment: You need to store the result of the select somewhere. If you want to return a result, use a function. Procedures aren't meant to return something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code almost every line is not good.

First if you want to write stored procedures in Postgres, please start with the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql.html). The concept of stored procedures in MSSQL is significantly different to that in Oracle, DB2, and certainly different to that in Postgres. PLpgSQL in Postgres is similar to Oracle's PL/SQL. The best thing to do, is to forget all that you know about stored procedures and start from scratch.

The errors:

1. procedures in Postgres cannot return data - only functions can do this - in your example you probably need a table function.

   ```
   CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION officekit.testsp(mode text)
   RETURNS TABLE(a text, b text, c text)
   AS $$
   BEGIN
     IF mode = 'test' THEN
       RETURN QUERY SELECT test.a, test.b, test.c FROM test;
     END IF;
   END;
   $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
   ```

Personally I don't like this style of programming. Functions should not just wrap queries. A lot of significant performance problems and architecture issues arise from the bad use of this possibility, but it depends on context.

2. Why is commit there? This code doesn't make any change in the database. There is no reason to call commit.

Comment: Ok thanks for the suggestion;Can I use same function to Insert ,Update ,delete and select from diffferent tables

Comment: @wasimlatheef - why you need it? It has not sense to mix DML (INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE) and SELECT functionality together. You can have only one function, but I am almost sure, so it is signal unhappy design.

Comment: Ok Thanks ,i will follow,Currently Im looking to Migrate to Linux,Can you suggest best DBMS fully supported on Linux;

Comment: The best DBMS on Linux? It depends on what you want, what you need, and what you know. Usually almost open source databases has origin on Linux, so are supported better than on windows - Postgres, MySQL, Firebird. Almost all SQL databases are older than 20 years, so it is mature software. There is not best database, maybe there is best database for some purpose